# Como usar el "MouseMove" en una aplicacion Forms en Visual Basic 2019

Tags: c#, windows-forms, exe

Bueno creo que ya se dan la idea de lo que quiero hacer :V, estoy en primer año de programación y se c++ y python, me motive a desarrollar esto, pero me falta poder aplicar esa función al botón NO, para cuando el cursor pase por encima lo envié a una posicion Random.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que deberías leer con urgencia [ask], en el título no va *doy x por y*, sino una inducción al problema

Comment: 5 estrellas en dónde?

Comment: El código va como texto, además debes indicar exactamente cual es el fallo con tu código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas usar esta API de Windows

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    //Moving the mouse 
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    //Simulate left mouse button press 
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    //Simulate left mouse button up 
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    //Simulate mouse right click 
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    //Simulate the right mouse button up 
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
    //Analog mouse button press 
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
    //Analog mouse middle button lift 
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
    //Indicate whether absolute coordinates are used 
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

  //Esto dentro de un boton
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);//1.5 Segundos para mover el mouse
                    SetCursorPos(1414, 117);//Posicion a donde  vas a enviar tu texto o pulsaciones
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    SendKeys.Send("^v");//Aqui un ejemplo de pegar un texto
```

Espero te sirva.

DS